# How to make ORDER by faster in cypher?

Tags: performance, neo4j, cypher

**PART-I:**
I have a lucene index on property a1 of a node n, and I have a cypher with

```
ORDER BY n.a1 DESC
```

Will it take advantage of the lucene index while sorting the results?

**PART-II:**
Lets assume i have similar indexes on a1, a2, a3...aN(individually), and I have a cypher with

```
ORDER BY n.a1, n.a2 DESC, n.a3... n.aN DESC
```

Will it take advantage of the indexes or, do i have to define some kind of a multi field index separately for this particular combination of the fields and asc/desc ?

Comment: Can you post your full query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Part I.**

No. From the Java API you can add Lucene sort query objects.

**Part II**

No, see above.

The sorting happens without using any indexes just the results that are part of your query.

The index is only used to lookup nodes for starting points.